# Qt designer failed to start due to no qt plugin initialized error in pyqt5 Python

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am working with  `python-3.6` and have installed `pyqt5` and `pyqt5-tools`. I need to start the `qt-designer` which is present inside this directory `C:\Python3.6\Lib\site-packages\pyqt5_tools\Qt\bin`. When I am launching the `qt desginer` I am getting below error:

[image]

I have tried reinstalling it but it still fails to start. Is there anyone who has faced this issue. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After copying plugins from pyqt5 to pasting them in the dir where designer.exe was present, it started working fine